# Why do functions print automatically when put in 'if' statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Why is it that when this code is executed, I would get 'hi'?

Thanks!

```
def b():
    print("hi")
def c():
    return True
if b() == 'hi':
    print("Done")
```

Comment: If there's no explicit `return` statement `None` is returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing printing to the console with returning a value. Your function implicitly returns `None` if you do not return anything from it so it is never equal to `'hi'`. Your `b()` does print - and not return its `'hi'`

```
def b():
    print("hi")  # maybe uncomment it if you do not want to print it here
    return "hi"  # fix like this (which makes not much sense but well :o)

def c():
    return True
if b() == 'hi':
    print("Done")
```

You can test it like this:

```
def test():
    pass

print(test())
```

Outputs:

```
None
```

Further readings:

- [about the return statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#the-return-statement)
- [about defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (read the paragraph below the second `fib`-CodeBlock example - it tells you about `None`)

---

One even more important thing to read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - it gives you tips on how to fix code yourself and find errors by debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're doing is saying `if b()`, which runs the b() function and prints "hi" is equal to "hi", print "done", but since your function prints "hi", rather than returning "hi", it will never equal true.

Try this:

```
def b():
    return "hi"
def c():
    return True
if b() == 'hi':
    print("Done")
```